# Can I use GROUP BY in an UPDATE table MySQL transaction

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
m3clients
client    balance
joe       0
mark      0
jeff      0
```

and

```
m3orders
client    balance
joe       -100
joe       50
joe       -45
mark      -10
mark      5
jeff      60
```

I need to update the m3clients table balance field with a sum of balances attached to their name.

So, it would read something like this:

```
m3clients
joe    -95
mark   -5
jeff   60
```

Where in the update statement do I put the GROUP BY statement?

```
UPDATE m3clients
INNER JOIN m3orders ON (m3orders.client = m3clients.client)
SET m3clients.balance = m3orders.balance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
UPDATE m3clients m
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT client,SUM(balance) as bal
   FROM m3orders 
   GROUP by client) a ON m.client = a.client
SET m.balance = a.bal
```

This uses a subquery to do the SUM of balance for every cliente and then you join it with your m3clients table to be able to update it with the balance calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the balance of every client in a subquery and join the result with table `m3clients`.

```
UPDATE  m3clients
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT client, SUM(balance) balance
            FROM    m3orders 
            GROUP   BY client
        ) cal ON m3clients.client = cal.client
SET     m3clients.balance = cal.balance
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bb90e/1)

Comment: This worked, once I realized that you were naming the SUM(balance) AS 'balance'. I just thought you were trying to add balance again, and I didn't understand. Thank you for the help!